# How can I encode a VRO file to an AVI file

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I have a Canon hand held camera that writes video to a mini-dvd disc. The disc contains a file with a VRO extension which ffmpeg was quite happy to process into an AVI that I could then load into Kdenlive for editing. However, when playing the AVI using Ubuntu's standard media play, the audio was badly out of sync with the image. Also the video failed to play under Windows using media player.

So, the question is, what options would best convert the VRO file without losing quality into something that can be edited using kdenlive, plays in the standard Ubuntu media player without audio syncing problems and plays under windows too.

Comment: Talking to a collegue, it seems the sync problem might be due to errors in the audio stream confusing the conversion process.

Comment: I would advise to change the title to something like "How can I encode a VRO file to a AVI file?"

Comment: Good call Davy - have done that.

Comment: @Davy: Transcode rather than encode would have been more correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VRO is the DVD Video Recording Format, it seems to be a wrapper around regular VOB files, according to [this topic](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=46358&start=0) you can use the open-source program [dvd-vr](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programs/dvd-vr/) to extract those VOB files from the VRO files. After that you can just use your regular DVD encoding software to convert it to a smaller format.

Comment: I've just downloaded dvd-vr and it splits the VRO into VOBs easily enough (assuming one if OK using make!). The VOBs load into kdenlive without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a command-line utility like [transcode](http://www.transcoding.org/cgi-bin/transcode?General_Information), which makes use of ffmpeg but has an easier interface. There are some good examples to follow on the [examples](http://www.transcoding.org/cgi-bin/transcode?Examples) page.